# get passedTime details using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`moment.js` currently has `fromNow()` method to get passed time. The only problem I have is that there's no details in `fromNow` method! for example the `fromNow` method returns `1 Month` but I want to show `1 Month and 5 days` to user.

Currently I gave up and tried to manually implement it using `diff()` method to get diff passed `days`, `months` and `years` and manually generate the desired output..

The exact problem is that the diff days may goes up to month and years and I don't know to subtract them to get to desired results...

```
function passedTimeMoment(date: number | undefined): string {
  if (date === undefined)
    return '';

  const years = moment().startOf('day').diff(date, 'years');
  const months = moment().startOf('day').diff(date, 'months');
  const days = moment().startOf('day').diff(date, 'days');

  let dateString: string = '';

  if (years > 0) {
    dateString += years + ' years and';
  }
  if (months > 0) {
    dateString += months + ' month and';
  }
  dateString += days + ' days ago';

  return dateString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to be a little inventive here. Since momentJs uses ranges as they mention here -> [Moment.fromNow()](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/02-fromnow).

You can replicate a bit of that behavior in your own approach and do something like this in your code snippet

```
  if (years > 0) {
    dateString += years + ' years and ';
  }
  months = months - years * 12;
  if (months > 0) {
    dateString += months + ' month and ';
  }
  days = days - months * 28;
  if(days > 0){
    dateString += days + ' days ago';
  }

  return dateString;
```